# JasperReports in grails

Tags: grails, jasper-reports

I have installed jasper plugins for my grails application.
Then in the list.groovy page I have modify the code:

```
<g:paginate total="${Race.count()}" /> </div>  
<g:jasperReport jasper="all-races" format="PDF" name="All Races" />
```

then I start the grails app. In list.gsp page, an pdf icon has been displayed. but when I click on it. it's showing error:

```
Error 500: Executing action [index] of controller [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.jasper.JasperController] in plugin [jasper] caused exception: null
Servlet: grails
URI: /cirnele/grails/jasper.dispatch
Exception Message: No such report spec: /reports/all-races (jasper or .jrxml) 
Caused by: No such report spec: /reports/all-races (jasper or .jrxml) 
Class: Unknown 
At Line: [-1] 
Code Snippet:
```

Actually I dont know how to use iReport to generate jasper file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the exception states, make sure you have your report generated in the directory you specified.  You may want to take a look at [this documentation](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/ireport-designer-getting-started).

Comment: Hi! The link appears broken now. Also can you please point me to a walk-through for report generation in JasperGrails ? The one OP is following is built on older version of Grails. I could not able to make it run in Grails 2.1.1. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @tusar  Sorry, I haven't used jasper on Grails 2.1.1 so I can't provide much help.  I've updated the link, though.

Comment: Thank you so much ! That fixed link serves all what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

Copy your .jrxml file into e.x grails-app\reports then add this line into your config.groovy or simply point it to the location of your report.

```
jasper.dir.reports = 'reports'
```